How to push docker image to vps through ssh scp bitbucket pipeline
I am generate docker image from my bitbucket pipeline. Now after generating, I want to copy that .tar file to my vps (virtual private server) but somehow it is not working. I do not user docker hub
I have following .yaml file
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build and Test
          script:
            - IMAGE_NAME=$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG
            - docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${IMAGE_NAME}
            - docker save ${IMAGE_NAME} --output "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar"
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
          artifacts:
            - "*.tar"
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - scp -i $PP_SSH_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar" root@111.11.11.11:/home
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.2
              variables:
                SSH_USER: "root"
                SERVER: "111.11.11.11"
                SSH_KEY: $PP_SSH_KEY
                COMMAND: |
                  docker load -i "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar"
                  docker stop ${IMAGE_NAME} || true
                  docker rm "${IMAGE_NAME}" || true
                  docker run -d --name "${IMAGE_NAME}" -p 80:8800 "${IMAGE_NAME}":latest "${IMAGE_NAME}"
          services:
            - docker

It got failed at line -
- scp -i $PP_SSH_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "${IMAGE_NAME}.tar" root@111.11.11.11:/home

I have created PP_SSH_KEY in pipeline variable with base64 encode private key value.
It is not working from the bitbucket pipeline but it is working from my machine.
How should I copy that docker image file to my vps server?
